# Problem with hiding ECB buttons in Sharepoint

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010

I have a serious trouble hiding ECB buttons in SharePoint 2010. I've read an article that says that I must create a copy of core.js file and comment the AddCheckInCheckOutMenuItems function. I've tried it and I have also referenced my custom core.js file. However it is still not working. It seems like Sharepoint is only calling the function from core.js or its somehow overwriting my function . Anyone here with the same problem or anyone that could solve this issue ?

Thank you for your time .

Answer (score 0):

Please check the order in which you refer the js. It should be like :

```
<!--It is important to refer core.js even if you create and refer customcore.js-->
<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="core.js" Defer="true" runat="server"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="customcore.js" Defer="true" runat="server"/>
```

You can also check the jquery approach to hide ECB items in this post : http://extreme-sharepoint.com/2011/10/29/hide-menu-ecb/